# Jansson lib parser

Tags: c, json

I'm developing an application written in C to communicate with an API web server using libcurl. I parsed successfully some  JSON responses but I failed to parse this one (the simplest one).
 - Code

```
  void auth_parser(char* serverResponse,struct ParsedAuthResponse *responseP)
    {
      char* json_text;
      json_t *root;
      json_error_t error;
      const char* error_text=NULL;
      const char* message_text=NULL;


      json_text=malloc(strlen(serverResponse)+strlen("[]")+1);
      if (!json_text)
      {
          printf( "not enough memory\n");
          return ;
      } 
      strcpy(json_text,"[");
      json_text=strcat(json_text,serverResponse);
      json_text=strcat(json_text,"]");
      root = json_loads(json_text, 0, &error);
      SCM_FREE(json_text); 


      if(!json_is_array(root)) 
      {
            printf( "error: on line %d: %s\n", error.line, error.text);
            return;
      }
 json_t *error_obj,*message_obj;
  data = json_array_get(root, 0);
  if(!json_is_object(data))
  {

        printf("error1 \n");
        json_decref(root);

  }
   else
  {
        printf("OK1 \n");
  }

  error_obj= json_object_get(data, "error");
  if(error_obj)
  {
      if(!json_is_string(error_obj))
      {

            printf( "error2 \n");
            json_decref(root);
      }
      else
      {
      error_text=json_string_value(error_obj);
      printf("error_text=%s",error_text);
      }

      message_obj=json_object_get(data, "message");
      if(!json_is_string(message_obj))
      {
          printf( "error3 \n");
          json_decref(root);
      }
      else
      {
          message_text=json_string_value(message_obj);
          printf("message_text=%s",message_text);
          printf("OK3 \n");
      }
     }
return;
}
```

This is the JSON object to parse :

> {"error":4,"message":"Authentication Failed - You do not have
>   permissions to access the service"}

It fails at **error2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking if the value of the error key is a string and it is failing because it is an integer.

Try replacing :

```
if(!json_is_string(error_obj))
```

with

```
if(!json_is_integer(error_obj))
```